# Disabling icons in jsTree V3

Tags: jstree

Can anyone confirm whether this works as it seems to have no effect on my tree config (default icons are always displayed):

```
                  "themes": {
                      "icons": false
                  }
```

Answer (score 0):

in jstree v3 the theme part is in the core part so it should be written in it.i am writing 
a sample code hope it helps.

```
$('#treeloaddiv').jstree({
        'core' : {
          'data' : {
            "url" : "/jstreedemo/JSTreeDemoServlet",
            "type":"post",
            "dataType" : "json", // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
            "data" : function (node) {  
                    return { "id" : node.id };
            }
          },
          "themes" : {
              "icons" : false
            }
        }
      });
```